# error in deploying jar to remote repository in maven

Tags: maven-2

i am trying to deploy a jar file from my local machine to a remote machine which has an artifactory. I tried the following command :

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=<some-id> 
                       -DartifactId=<some-artifact> 
                       -Dversion=<version> 
                       -Dpackaging=jar 
                       -Dfile=<path to the file in my local system>
                       -Durl=http://<ip of remote machine>:<port>/artifactory/repo/ 
                       -DrepositoryId=<artifactory -id in remote machine>
```

but on executing it gives error that:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'deploy'.
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Default Project
[INFO]    task-segment: [deploy:deploy-file] (aggregator-style)
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] One or more required plugin parameters are invalid/missing for 'deploy:
ploy-file'

[0] Inside the definition for plugin 'maven-deploy-plugin' specify the following
:

  <configuration>
   ...
 <url>VALUE</url>
 </configuration>

-OR-

on the command line, specify: '-Durl=VALUE'
```

As i am specifying the value for Durl in my command why am i still getting this error?
How to resolve this?
The maven version is 2.2.1
Thanks.

Comment: Not sure about the Maven error itself, but I did notice that the deployment URL points to Artifactory's "/repo" repository (which is a global virtual aggregator of all the repositories in the instance); since it's a virtual repository, one cannot deploy to it; you should point the URL to one of Artifactory's local repositories (libs-release-local, etc.).

Comment: i changed it to local repo name but still same error

Comment: yes i got it wokring now..actually was putting the wrong url ..thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Answered in comments:

> Not sure about the Maven error itself, but I did notice that the
>   deployment URL points to Artifactory's "/repo" repository (which is a
>   global virtual aggregator of all the repositories in the instance);
>   since it's a virtual repository, one cannot deploy to it; you should
>   point the URL to one of Artifactory's local repositories
>   (libs-release-local, etc.). –  noamt Jan 20 '12 at 8:44
>
> i changed it to local repo name but still same error –  pranay Jan 20
>   '12 at 13:02
>
> yes i got it wokring now..actually was putting the wrong url ..thanks
>   a lot –  pranay Jan 25 '12 at 6:33